# How to style div float: left and right correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm just playing with some really basic html, and I'm trying to get myself caught up. The last time I really did anything structure wise tables were still ideal and dominant. So I'm using divs.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">Please fill out the following information
    <div>Name, email, or alias:</div>
    <div><input type="text" id="user"></div>
    <div>Master Password:</div>
    <div><input type="password" id="pwdOne"></div>
    <div>Re-enter:</div>
    <div><input type="password" id="pwdTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Which resulted in this:

[image: A page that is not formatted correctly]

So I did some digging and looked at some formatting example and re-did it to be this instead:

```
<div style="text-align:center; clear: both;">Please fill out the following information</div>
<div style="float: left;">Name, email, or alias:</div>
<div style="float: right;"><input type="text" id="user"></div>
<div style="float: left;">Master Password:</div>
<div style="float: right;"><input type="password" id="pwdOne"></div>
<div style="float: left;">Re-enter:</div>
<div style="float: right;"><input type="password" id="pwdTwo"></div>
```

and to my understanding this should be correct, but now I'm getting:
[image: Not any better]

How do I differentiate each individual div when floating left and right so they stack correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add a class clear that clean the float like this a `br` or `div` is the same:

```
<div style="text-align:center; clear: both;">Please fill out the following information</div>
<div style="float: left;">Name, email, or alias:</div>
<div style="float: right;"><input type="text" id="user"></div>
<br class="clear">
<div style="float: left;">Master Password:</div>
<div style="float: right;"><input type="password" id="pwdOne"></div>
<br class="clear">
<div style="float: left;">Re-enter:</div>
<div style="float: right;"><input type="password" id="pwdTwo"></div>
<br class="clear">

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCWHv/)

Comment: Could just add clear to the labels instead of having extra tags.

Comment: sure but sincerly I prefer this, in this case because OP can understand well html I think, is only to make more clean the problem for him, but thanks for the tip next time I use your solution @JamesMontagne